# How to transfer variable from ajax to php and php to ajax with JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, laravel

I am using laravel 5.0.

I have a controller named `pesananController` like this:

```
public function ambilnamakomp(Request $request)
{
    $data = DB::table('komputer')->where('id', $idkomp);
    $hasil = json_encode($data);
    return $hasil;
}
```

view bookhari.blade.php:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var namakomp = "";
var urltemp = "/ambilnamakomp/" + idkomp;
$(document).ready(function () {
            $.get(urltemp, function(){ 
                namakomp = jQuery.parseJSON(hasil)
            }); 
        });
alert(namakomp);
</script>
```

routes I like this:

```
Route::get('/ambilnamakomp/{id}', 'pesananController@ambilnamakomp');
```

I wanted to take the form of data records in the database using ajax.

I do not understand how to send a variable from php ajax and then process it in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

In your laravel code, you can use response helper with json method:

```
public function ambilnamakomp(Request $request)
{
    $data = DB::table('komputer')->where('id', $idkomp);
    return (new Illuminate\Http\Response())->json($data);
}
```

You can get data in your JQuery $.get function like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var namakomp = "";
var urltemp = "/ambilnamakomp/" + idkomp;
$(document).ready(function () {
            $.get(urltemp, function(data){ 
                //data is object from php script
                namakomp = data;
            }); 
        });
alert(namakomp);
</script>
```